# Remove the first element from a multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Form this array, how can I remove the first element of `Provinces` ?

```
Array
(
    [Country] => Canada
    [Provinces] => Array
        (
            [0] => Quebec
            [1] => Ontario
            [2] => British Columbia
        )
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the first items in the array for the key name `Provinces` and the numerical keys do not have to be preserved, you could also use [array_splice](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
$arr = [
    "Country" => "Canada",
    "Provinces" => [
        "Quebec",
        "Ontario",
        "British Columbia"
    ]
];
array_splice($arr["Provinces"], 0, 1);
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/OSOrt)

Or using unset to keep the numerical keys:

```
unset($arr['Provinces'][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `unset()`:

`unset( $myArray['Cities'][0] )`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Answer (score -3):

You can do both way but difference is that when you use unset will remove an element by its key, say unset( $myArray['country']) will remove the country key value pair.

if you want to remove first element in multidimensional array then you can easily d t with array_shift(); it will remove all the child array of this particular element.

suppose it is a location array

```
   $location = Array
       (
        [Country] => Canada
        [Provinces] => Array
         (
            [0] => Quebec
            [1] => Ontario
            [2] => British Columbia
        )
)

// Removing first array item
$location_new = array_shift($planets);
print_r($location_new);//it will give **Canada**
//and now
print_r($location);//it will give the 

 Array
       (
        [Provinces] => Array
         (
            [0] => Quebec
            [1] => Ontario
            [2] => British Columbia
        )
)
```